# If $f_X$ is a pdf of the r.v. $X$ what would be $g(s)=\int_{\mathbb R}f_X(x)\delta (s-x)dx$?

Tags: probability

Let $X$ a real r.v. and $f_X$ it's pdf. What would be $$g(s)=\int_{\mathbb R}f_X(x)\delta (s-x)\,\mathrm d x,$$
where $\delta $ is the Dirac distribution ? It look to be a pdf of some r.v. but which one ?

The problem is exactly as follow : Let $X$ and $Y$ two $\mathcal N(0,1)$ r.v. with join pdf $f_{X,Y}$ (they are not supposed independent). Let $s=|x-y|$. Consider $$g(s)=\int_{\mathbb R^2}f_{X,Y}(x,y)\delta (s-|x-y|)\,\mathrm d x\,\mathrm d y.$$

What is exactely $g(s)$ ?

Answer (score 0):

Let $\phi$ denote the $\mathcal{N}(0,\,1)$ pdf. Since $X-Y\sim\mathcal{N}(0,\,2)$ has pdf $\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\phi(\tfrac{x}{\sqrt{2}})$, $S:=|X-Y|$ [has pdf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-normal_distribution) $g(s)=\sqrt{2}\phi(\tfrac{s}{\sqrt{2}})=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\exp-\tfrac{s^2}{4}$ on $\Bbb R^+$.

Comment: in what it answer to my question ?

Comment: @user623855 See my edit.

Comment: Can we say in general that $f(X_1,...,X_n)$ has pdf $$g(s)=\int_{\mathbb R^n}f_{X_1,...,X_n}(x_1,...,x_n)\delta (s-f(x_1,...,x_n))dx_1...dx_n \ \ ?$$

Comment: @user623855 Yes. PMFs of functions of discrete variables have a similar form.